# Where to find historical international export data?

Tags: international-trade

Writing a paper on revealed comparative advantage and it’d be super helpful to have historical data on exports of different goods going back 30+ years. Ideally I’d be able to filter by industry and reporter with just one query.

e.g. finding total New Zealand exports of bovine meat (HS code 0202) between 1990 and 2020 with just one query.

All of the sites I’ve found so far are either extremely laggy, lack data or cannot take multiple criteria for the search. Is there any database I could use?

Comment: Why don't you just download all the data from one of the sources you identified and filter with Excel or a statistics program.